# How to load .npy file contents into pandas dataframe?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have data files in .npy format and I want to load it to pandas dataframe library, in order to further processing.

I tried read_csv method of pandas library, which I used in other scripts to load files.

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('Frequency.npy')
```

Following error is thrown

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 702, in parser_f
    return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 429, in _read
    parser = TextFileReader(filepath_or_buffer, **kwds)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 895, in __init__
    self._make_engine(self.engine)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 1122, in _make_engine
    self._engine = CParserWrapper(self.f, **self.options)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 1853, in __init__
    self._reader = parsers.TextReader(src, **kwds)
  File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 542, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.__cinit__
  File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 782, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._get_header
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x93 in position 0: invalid start byte
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try [`numpy.load`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.load.html) with [`pd.DataFrame`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html#pandas-dataframe) constructor:

```
pd.DataFrame(np.load("file.npy"))
```

Full example:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"col1": np.arange(10), "col2": np.random.randint(0,10,(10))})
print(df)
#    col1  col2
# 0     0     4
# 1     1     1
# 2     2     0
# 3     3     0
# 4     4     4
# 5     5     8
# 6     6     5
# 7     7     8
# 8     8     0
# 9     9     1

# Save .npy file
np.save("temp", df)

# Load .npy file as DataFrame
df_2 = pd.DataFrame(np.load("temp.npy"), columns=["col1", "col2"])
```

Comment: I think this answer gave the opposite solution to the question

Comment: @Eliethesaiyan Have a look at the update, let me kwon if it's better